# Is it safe to use the cable used in Portable Battery Charger and connect to the phone via the PC USB?

Tags: cables, charger

Every portable battery charger have a cable. That cable is usually connecting the PC USB port to the Portable Battery Charger so as to charge the battery inside the Portable Battery Charger.

So, is it safe to use it to connect the PC USB Port to the phone directly? (The reason that I asked is because each cable have resistance levels, which I am concern if it will affect the charging of the phone if used in this way and will it cause damage to the phone or the phone battery or the cable or the PC USB port.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's very likely completely fine. You should be getting 5V on the non-PC end of the cable and your phone will limit current appropriately for charging. The only issue I can see is some companies will make cables proprietary by adding voltage dividers to the data pins, perhaps this is the resistance levels you're talking about? However, this will only mean your phone will not charge, it won't be damaged. This, of course, is all assuming the connector is correct.